# Solve casting error in lambda

Tags: c#, linq, casting, lambda

I use the following code in wcf ria services (Silverlight App):

```
 public partial class BillingWaterDomainService : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<BilingWaterEntities>
    {
        public ObservableCollection<PaymentSummary> GetPaymentSummary(long requestId)
        {
            var paymentSummaries = new ObservableCollection<PaymentSummary>();

            var result = GetRequestCostDetailsByRequestId(requestId);
            foreach (var requestCostDetail in result.Where(r=>r.BranchCostId.HasValue))
            {
                if (requestCostDetail.Debtor.HasValue)
                {
                    RequestCostDetail detail = requestCostDetail;

                    long? costCustomerPrice = 0;                       
                    costCustomerPrice =
                        result.Where(
                            r => r.CostCustomerDetail.CostCustomerType.CostTypeId == detail.BranchCostDetail.CostType && r.Creditor.HasValue).
                            Sum(r => r.Creditor != null ? r.Creditor.Value : 0);

                    paymentSummaries.Add(new PaymentSummary()
                                             {
                                                 PaymentTitle = requestCostDetail.BranchCostDetail.CostType1.CostTitle,
                                                 Price = requestCostDetail.Debtor.Value-(costCustomerPrice.HasValue ? costCustomerPrice.Value:0)
                                             });
                }
            }


            return paymentSummaries;
        }
    }
```

When i try execute this code, i have following error:

> Invoke Operation
>   'GetPaymentSummary' failed.The cast to value type 'Int64' failed
>   because the materialized value is null.Either the result type 's
>   generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type

this error in the following line of code:

```
costCustomerPrice =result.Where(
                            r => r.CostCustomerDetail.CostCustomerType.CostTypeId == detail.BranchCostDetail.CostType && r.Creditor.HasValue).
                            Sum(r => r.Creditor != null ? r.Creditor.Value : 0);
```

And This piece of code:

```
r => r.CostCustomerDetail.CostCustomerType.CostTypeId
```

how can i solve this problem?!

Comment: where is `GetPaymentSummary` called?

Comment: Which line is failing? Please show a complete stack trace.

Comment: I called 'GetPaymentSummary' in the client-side silverlight application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `r => r.CostCustomerDetail.CostCustomerType.CostTypeId` is null for some entries. Try adding a condition:

```
results.Where(r => r.CostCustomerDetail.CostCustomerType.CostTypeId.HasValue)
    .Where(...
```

Or maybe even `r.CostCustomerDetail.CostCustomerType` is sometimes null.

You can also do this:

```
... .Select(r => r.Creditor != null ? r.Creditor.Value : 0)
       .DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

At some point, you are trying to call `GetPaymentSummary` and passing a null argument into it. You say you're calling it from client-side - somehow, a null value is getting passed in as `requestId`.

You may want to change the method to accept a `long?`, and check initially that it `HasValue` - this way you can handle the case of bad input without hard failing.

Comment: Value of **RequestId** is not Null.Error in this line:    costCustomerPrice =result.Where(
                            r => r.CostCustomerDetail.CostCustomerType.CostTypeId == detail.BranchCostDetail.CostType && r.Creditor.HasValue).
                            Sum(r => r.Creditor != null ? r.Creditor.Value : 0);

Answer (score 0):

Befor Sum method used ToList method.
if you change your this code:

```
costCustomerPrice =
                        result.Where(
                            r => r.CostCustomerDetail.CostCustomerType.CostTypeId == detail.BranchCostDetail.CostType && r.Creditor.HasValue).
                            Sum(r => r.Creditor != null ? r.Creditor.Value : 0);
```

to this code:

```
costCustomerPrice =
                        result.Where(
                            r => r.CostCustomerDetail.CostCustomerType.CostTypeId == detail.BranchCostDetail.CostType && r.Creditor.HasValue).ToList().
                            Sum(r => r.Creditor != null ? r.Creditor.Value : 0);
```

Your Program running with out any error!